# Threads in Tridion Event System

Tags: workflow, bundles

I am trying to implement Wrokflow on unpublishing of pages in Tridion 2013 SP1.
I have a doubt about number of threads in Event System while Un-Publishing

What my approach is as follows :

I am creating a new bundle X or getting the already created bundle X on each page unpublishing.
I am adding my page into the bundle X .
I am thinking of starting the Workflow on Bundle X.

Will there be any kind of threading issues while unpublishing more then one item .

Answer (score 2):

(Un)Publishing in Tridion is done by a separate service. Any request to un(publish) are put in a queue regardless they are from eventsystem/gui/any other place. If you start workflow during unpublishing from event system, keep in mind that your unpublish operation is not going to be blocked, if you manually block it you might potentially cause a lot of timeout.

Question: Which event do you plan on subscribing to?

Comment: This is the Event i am subscribing to :    EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<Page, UnPublishEventArgs>(PageUnPublishWorkFlowChange, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);